# My Schengen tourist visa C is expired and I want to go back in my country

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, overstaying, filipino-citizens

I want to go back to the Philippines, but I overstayed 8 months in Paris and my Schengen tourist visa C expired. Is there any problem if I go back to my country?

Comment: OP, please check that I have edited your question correctly; in particular, that your Schengen tourist visa is already expired.

Comment: Sorry bro i don't speak in english very well can i go back in my country without any consequences or pblem in airport in paris? For example i buy plane ticket to go back in PH  is there a problem in the cdg airport or any penalties?

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus

Comment: As you can see from the linked question, there *are* likely to be issues. At the minimum you will be recorded in a database of overstayers, and your chances of ever getting another Schengen visa are poor. Such a long overstay suggests off-the-books work, too. The other question mentions threats of jail or fines, but to be quite honest I think it unlikely that someone returning to a country that is less well developed economically will have the ability to pay a large fine, and they would rather see you leave. You may be given an official re-entry ban.

Comment: What if i don't pay the fine would i go to jail or they just want me to leave the paris? i just want to be back home i don't care if i not given a visa in future or ban me i want to go back home but i can't pay the fine because i dont have a money my money is excactly for plane ticket only pls help me what to do

Comment: What to do is leave. You will have an unpleasant interview with the border guard. I'm sure in theory they _could_ fine you, and probably imprison you until the fine was paid. In practice for someone from the Third World, my _guess_ is they will figure the odds of ever seeing substantial payment from you is small, let you leave, and never let you in again. Your chances of a visa to US, UK, etc. are also very poor. This was not a good decision.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew suggests, you will be allowed to go back, but it is unlikely you will get a Schengen visa in future, given the length of time you have overstayed.